# Named routes for nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm actually having trouble finding the documentation for this so if you have a link handy that would be really appreciated too.

So I have:

```
resources :users do 
  resources :posts, only: [:index, :create, :show] 
  end
```

I wanted to access the index action of `posts` through a named route. I tried this: `<%= link_to 'User Posts', user_posts_path %>` but it said it was missing `user_id`. Any ideas?

Comment: It's missing `user_id`. You have to provide one if you want to use nested resources, otherwise it makes no sense.

Comment: Visit [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the nested resource routes, you would need to provide the reference id of the parent resource. In your case resource `user`. You could do: `user_posts_path(user)`. The route generated would be something like: `/users/1/posts` where 1 is the `:user_id` or if you would rather want a route like: `/users/posts` you should do:

```
resources :users do
  collection do
    resources :posts
  end
end
```

Find full [routing documentation here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: this is what I was looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

it's asking for `user_id` because you're defining :users as a resource, change it for a namespace instead:

```
namespace :users do 
  resources :posts, only: [:index, :create, :show] 
end
```

Comment: note that changing to namespace would assume you're nesting posts_controller under a users module as such: `Users::PostController`

Comment: that's right, I forgot to mention that... maybe you can just change your posts resource to `user_posts` and avoid the namespace. thx @oreoluwa